# Command in batch file to open up a .jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, registry, exe

I created a registry that associates my `.mike` file with my notepad application I created.

I think that the issue lies somewhere in the registry since it can only run `.exe` files, although, I've heard that `.batch` and `.exe` files are one of the same thing.

I tried to open up a text file that I created using my application, and I received the message "`[blank] is not a valid Win32 Application`".

What is the command in the batch file to open up the file in the application, after double clicking on the file?

Comment: Just as some educational information: a batch file is a command script file (executed by the operating system's command processor - on recent Windows versions that's `cmd.exe`), while a `.exe` (executable) file is a stand-alone executable made up of binary code (it runs by itself on the operating system). They're nothing like "one of the same thing".

Comment: How are you launching your application?  And how did you create the file associations?  Perhaps [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749986.aspx) may help clarify things?

Comment: @DanielPryden I hope I am interpreting your first question properly, I launch the application by double-clicking on the .jar file...?  I created the file associations (perhaps this isn't the correct terminology) by creating a text document similar to [this blog post](http://registryeditor.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-do-you-make-your-own-file-extension.html).  Thank you for the reference to the TechNet article.  I'll see what I can do and let you know what happens!

Comment: @Mike: OK, that's part of your problem.  `.jar` files aren't natively executable either, so Windows uses this very same file association mechanism to figure out that `.jar` files are "opened with" `javaw.exe`, which will run the Java code (by launching the main class defined by the `MANIFEST.MF` file inside the JAR).  Likewise, as Ken White pointed out, `.bat` files aren't executable either, but are launched by "opening" them with `cmd.exe`.  You'll need to set up the command line used by the file association to be the *full* command line to launch your application, starting with `javaw.exe`.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thank you for explaining .jar files, it really didn't sink in when I tried to learn about them in class.  However, the last line in your last post has got me scratching my head... I have no idea what to type into command prompt to launch the application (as well as how to save the command into a text document and of what type).  If I am understanding this correctly, I am going to have to move my .jar file to the bin sub-folder in my jre6 folder to successfully execute the command... maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments on your question, it looks like you just want to construct a command line to launch your JAR file.  That's simple:

> ```
> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe -jar C:\Path\To\YourApplication.jar
> ```

(Where `%JAVA_HOME%` refers to the directory where you installed Java.)

Sun's site has [some comprehensive documentation on the `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` launchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html).  (That particular link is a bit dated, as it refers to Java 1.4.2, but the launching mechanism hasn't changed since then.)

If you want to launch your application and open a file, the command line is likely to be something like:

> ```
> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe -jar C:\Path\To\YourApplication.jar C:\Path\To\SomeFile.txt
> ```

Then `"C:\\Path\\To\\SomeFile.txt"` will be passed to your `main()` method in its `String[] args` parameter.

Comment: @Mike: Feel free to open a new question if there's some specific aspect of this that you don't understand.

Comment: Okay. By saying that `%JAVA_HOME%` **refers**... does that mean that it references the location like in programming or references as in "insert your directory here"?  I've tried to do the change directory command (only `cd` to push back to the parent folder) in command prompt but it stays at the same directory, which tells me that it must be the root.  If it were to push back to C:\ I would add the rest of the directory that refers to the `javaw.exe` file.  Once again, I am sorry for so many questions.  I have little to no background on command prompt.

Comment: @Mike: You should definitely get familiar with the command prompt, as that will help you understand what's going on here. The `%`-syntax is used by DOS and the Windows command shell to indicate the expansion of an environment variable, which is like a variable in programming. It's common to set up an environment variable called `JAVA_HOME` to point at the Java installation folder (and many Java tools will expect that), but it isn't normally done by the JDK installer on Windows. So you can either set the variable yourself, or just replace it with your hardcoded path.

Comment: @Mike: As for your comment about `cd`, the DOS convention was for `cd` with no arguments to print the current directory instead of changing it, and the Windows command prompt follows that convention. (By contrast, in Unix and Unix-like systems, `cd` without any arguments takes you back to your user's home directory, and `pwd` is used to print the current working directory.) And due to the way drive letters work on Windows, `cd` will only change the working directory for your *current drive*, so if you have multiple drives (C:, D:, etc.) you'll need to select the correct drive first.

Comment: @Mike: That said, not all strings in the registry get environment variables expanded, and off the top of my head I don't know about the registry keys used for file associations. It is much more common to use an absolute path when setting up a file association.

Comment: I followed everything that you said to a 'T' and command prompt says `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I even tried opening it with a batch file that contained `start /min C:\Path\To\File.jar` instead of the hard coded path after `...-jar <my path>` (so `test.batch` where `<my path>` is).

Comment: @Mike: FYI, for basic command-prompt usage, you might be better served by asking questions at [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com).  In any case, the specific issue here is that the path contains a space character, but you didn't surround it with quotes.  Use `"C:\Program Files\Java\...\javaw.exe"` (with double quotes surrounding the path) and you should be fine.

Comment: Cool, it worked!  Thanks!  I suppose the reason why I am getting the message `"[blank] is not a valid Win32 Application"` is because I am giving the value in ...Open\command\ (of the registry) this: `...test.batch %1` and not `...test.exe %1`?

Comment: @Mike: Yes.  In the future, if you have follow-on questions, please ask them as new questions, instead of just adding a comment to an existing answer.  That will enable a wider audience of people to respond, instead of just me.  Also, if you have questions that are more about command-prompt usage and Windows itself, you should post those on StackOverflow's sister site [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).